# Display $scope doesn't works in my view

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to display a $scope value in my view but it doest'nt work.

My console.log with scope works.

Any idea ?

In my controller with Geolocation Plugin

```
    .controller('geoCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicPlatform', function($scope, $ionicPlatform) {
    function updateLoc($scope)
    {
        $scope.latitude2 = "wow";
        console.log("hello");
        console.log($scope.latitude);
        console.log($scope.longitude);
        console.log($scope.speed);
    }
        $scope.findGeolocation = function() {
            console.log("navigator.geolocation works");
            var onSuccess = function(position) {
                $scope.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                $scope.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                $scope.altitude = position.coords.altitude;
                $scope.speed = position.coords.speed;
                $scope.timestamp = position.timestamp;
                console.log($scope.longitude);
            updateLoc($scope);

        };
        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');

        };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);   
    }
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() { $scope.findGeolocation(); })

}])
```

In my view

```
<ion-view view-title="APP">
  <ion-content>
  <div ng-controller="geoCtrl">
    <p>Bonjour, {{ latitude2 }} </p>
    <p id="speed">Finding speed...</p>
    <p id="latitude">Finding latitude...</p>
    <p id="longitude">Finding longitude...</p>
   </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Thank you

Comment: `$scope.latitude2` is initialise in the function `updateLoc`, from what I can see it's never called so its value will be undefined.

Comment: i just update my code. it was called in my code, but to post my question in stackoverflow i had to delete some code. sorry about that

Comment: this line is strange for me `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);` . i don't have your code but i will use this instead  `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(onSuccess, onError);   `. onSuccess is executed in the geolocation service, so the scope is not the same and not shared. you have to make `getCurrentPosition()` return data and initialize it after

Comment: thank you for your answer. but i'd that navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition.then is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geolocation callback function is not running inside a digest - you need to tell angular that an update has been made. i.e.

```
        var onSuccess = function(position) {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                $scope.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                $scope.altitude = position.coords.altitude;
                $scope.speed = position.coords.speed;
                $scope.timestamp = position.timestamp;
                updateLoc($scope);
            });
        };
```